# Is there a function with domain spanning (-∞,∞), without a constant period, and that is neither decreasing nor increasing from or to either infinity?

Tags: functions

That is, a function that is neither even nor odd, doesn't repeat at a non-changing interval, and doesn't contain a middle (or center of three-plus- dimensional) about from which the output increases/decreases toward ∞ or -∞ with respect to the input value. The range might or might not go to either infinity or both (which if it does would suggest a vertical asymptote given that domain is not restricted).

If one exists, then what parent function form or forms can fit this? If there are multiple, then which one would be considered the simplest?

Comment: Technically the function $f$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x\neq 1$ fits your description. Maybe you could say something about why you are interested in the function you are looking for. It might give clues about properties you did not consider.

Comment: That example I suppose does fit the criterions: a constant function converted into a piecewise function by changing one value.  Although, I'm wondering about one a little more complex such as curves (not horizontal rays) going forever.

Comment: There are various ways to make a more interesting function. You could require it to be continuous and not to converge. (My function fails both criteria.)

Answer (score 1):

An example that is also continuous and does not converge to a limit in either direction is

$$ f(x) = (\pi+\arctan(x)) \sin (x).$$

This looks a little like a sinusoidal function, but the $(\pi+\arctan(x))$ term ensures that every cycle has a different amplitude, so they never exactly repeat and you have no odd or even symmetry, even if you translate the function sideways and vertically.

Comment: Is there an instance in which amplitude doesn't increase or decrease divergently toward + or - infinity (as is the case with harmonic growth)? Your answer does satisfy what I asked for. I guess I'm curious of one with minimal if any limits, that you can't construct a new graph or function from connecting the local mins or maxes that would then fail the aforestated criteria.